# Java Web Start Sandbox

Tags: java-web-start

Is there a way to know the location of Java sandbox or a system variable pointing to the sandbox?

Requirement is I need to run a java code locally which refers to a jar file in JWS Sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

The JWS sand-box is not a place but a security environment.  The classes for all-permissions, j2ee-application-client-permissions, and sand-boxed apps. are all stored under the same file path.

That location can be found by inspecting the [Java Control Panel](http://pscode.org/player.jnlp), (close the Java Cache Viewer,) activate the Settings button in the Temporary Internet Files section of the General tab.  See the Location section of the dialog that pops up, to find the path to the cache.  (1)

Note that to *launch* a JWS app. from code is quite easy..

```
// 1.6+
Desktop.browse(urlToTheJNLP);
```

---

1) Perhaps a better question though, is why do you actually (think you) need to do this, as opposed to using the apps. own JNLP/GUI?  What software is it?